# What is the Relation between Critical AoA with Chordline?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, aircraft-performance

I read [here](https://sites.google.com/site/zdrytchx/how-to/angle-of-attack) an explanation about angle of attack (AoA) as below:
*Overly long (forward-back wise) wings will generally have a smaller critical Angle of Attack while smaller ones will have more tolerance before stalling since Airflow starts to become turbulent in form of eddy currents*.

I never heard that claim before neither I ever read. I have searched in this forum if someone asked that question previously, but seem is not. I could not find. Is anyone have reference to this claim?

Comment: This might help you. [Similar Info](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/5047/how-does-chord-length-affect-wing-design)

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit unclear, but I think what he is trying to say is if you have longer chord, then separation of the flow will happen at lower AOA than with a shorter chord, which is plausible as the boundary layer grows thicker and thicker with longer distance. And stall=flow separation basically.