# What are these strange clouds on the wing and how do they form?

Tags: airliner

I am having a little trouble figuring out what these strange clouds are. You have a cloud forming off of a fighter jet when it breaks the sound barrier, but this is a different situation.[image]

Comment: @mins Ah, yes.  Thanks, A wee typo.  I'll edit.  Shall we delete the other comments to clean up?

Comment: `but this is a different situation.` no it's not. Both condensation caused by decompression

Comment: @Federico: Ethan doesn't say that (the link to the duplicate was added after he wrote)

Comment: Duplicate questions shouldn't be downvoted just for being duplicates. Being a duplicate doesn't make it a *bad* question, just a redundant one.

Comment: Ethan, what makes you think that breaking the sound "barrier" produces clouds? [Condensation cones](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9724/how-are-condensation-cones-created-by-supersonic-airplanes/9732#9732) happen only in subsonic flight.