# why induced drag decreases in supersonic speed?

Tags: aerodynamics, flight-dynamics, aerospace

In John Bertin's book Aerodynamics, it is written that the induced drag at subsonic speed decreases with the increase in wing aspect ratio but the opposite happens at supersonic speed so that in rectangular wings, induced drag decreases with decreasing wing aspect ratio , and it is explicitly stated in this book. that the effect of wing aspect ratio on induced drag is opposite to each other for subsonic and supersonic speeds

why ?

Comment: Does [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/26555) answer your question?